# Material UI - Apply props to pseudo-element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  box: {
    '&::before': {
      content: props => `${props.text}` // should be props.text from <Child /> (i.e. '111')
    }
  }
});

function Parent() {
    return <Child text="111" />
}

function Child(props) {
    const { text } = props;
    const classes = useStyles({ text });
    return <Box className={classes.box} />
}
```

How can I use props outside of the `<Child />`? I've tried data attribute but not working either. It seems `content` in the pseudo element is alittle bit different from other properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the props like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Box ,Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  box: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'black',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    '&:hover':{
      background:props=>props.hover 
    }
  }
});

function Parent() {
    return <Child hover='black' />
}

function Child(props) {
    //const props = { hover:'black' };
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return <Box className={classes.box}/>
}
```

In case of the pseudo element **::before** the syntax for the **content** property is a little different. We use additional inverted commas with the single commas like this:

```
 '&::before':{
      content:'"Some text"'
    }
```

In case we are passing props it will look like this:

```
'&::before':{
      content:props=>`"${props.content}"`
    }
```

For more info check out   [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Comment: I am setting the `content`, I think this one is different from other properties

Comment: @legenddaniel  Check the answer now. I have provided a solution for using props with content property.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props through in your useStyles call.

```
const classes = useStyles({text: 'asdf'})
```

Usage in your style definition would be something like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  box: {
    '&::before': {
      content: (props) => `${props.text}`
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, did you try putting the function on the top level parent `box`. Aka, `box: (props) =>({ &::before': { content: `${props.text}` }})`